# Why do calls to getDetails about a place in Google Maps Places Library keep returning QUERY_OVER_LIMIT error?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a location and I am placing a call to nearbySearch() of the Places library through Google Maps Javascript API to get restaurants within 1000 meters of my location. I then loop through the first 20 restaurants and make a call to getDetails() so that I can pull out the website of each restaurant. This works fine until I get to about the 10th restaurant, then I start to get QUERY_OVER_LIMIT status sent back from the getDetails call.

I have slowed down my calls to once every 300ms, but I still get the QUERY_OVER_LIMIT error. Based on what I've read, a call to the Places library every 300ms should be well within the limit. When I read documentation, it states that the per second limit for the Places API (which supposedly also applies to the Places Library of the Maps Javascript API) is 100 requests per second. When I log into my API dashboard, it tells me my per minute limit for the Places API is 6000 per minute. At one request every 300ms I am nowhere near my limits, so I'm at a loss to understand why I keep getting this error. Naturally I could slow it down much more, but this degrades the user experience and since the rate seems unpredictable, it's hard to settle on a rate that I know will produce consistent results.

[Places API Requests per Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eupx.png)

[Places API Request per Minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/955sE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Places Library [what you are using when you make getDetails() requests in Javascript] and Places API [the product your screenshots are talking about] are two different things with two different quotas.

When you use Places Library, Google rate limits you which is what you are seeing.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#UsageLimits

To be able to make more batch requests like you want, use Places API to get the Details for all of the places (which will get pricey pretty quick).
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details
https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#places-details